# Problems running my SFML script

Tags: c++, sfml

I have just recently installed SFML and am trying to learn it but cannot work out why its not working.

My script is from their tutorials, so its very short:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
// Create the main window
sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");

// Start main loop
bool Running = true;
while (Running)
{
    App.Display();
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem i am having is I am getting a couple of errors and am unsure what I have got wrong.... these are my errors:

Link to my error list is here (couldn't format the list nicely on here):

http://www.paste.to/MTYzNzE2Mw==

Hope some one can explain where I went wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with SFML itself but looks like an issue installing the library or a compilation issue in the linking stage(sfml library isnt being linked against).

Have you followed the getting started tutorials listed [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/) which setup compilation environment for sfml?

Comment: I've since updated it a bit to 2.0 but i still get issues. I followed this tutorial:
http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php

Comment: you might want to check, then, if the "Linker" related settings you have are still correct, else im clueless

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't install the library correctly.

Why don't you try sfml with CodeBlocks ?